# what is the limit of $\theta$ if $r\to 0$ when we have these conditions?

Tags: geometry, limits

the problem is based on this picture. [image]

at beginning or we say $t=0$, $P$ is a circle of which the center is at the point $(0,r)$, $r_0=1$ is the initial radius of this circle. $AB$ is a vector which has an angle $\theta$ from the $x$ axis, and this vector $AB$ will always on the tangent of the circle (the side close to $O$). We suppose that $A_0=(x_0,y_0)$ and the initial value of $\theta$ is $\theta_0$. we have also $|AP|=l=2$. the angle betwen $PA$ and $x$ axis is noted $\varphi$.
The vector $AB$ moves on the tangent of the circle with a velocity $-x$, so $A$ will be closer and closer to O. when the distance $AP=l<2r$, the radius becomes smaller, and then we have new $P,r$, but the new $r$ should satisfy $AP=2r$.

The question is : when $A\to O,r\to 0$, what is the limit of $\theta$?

I tried to use the differential method to get the result, but didn't make it. I know that the angle $\angle PAQ$ is always $\pi/6$ and $\dot{l}=2\dot{r}$. I don't know how to continue. thanks very much for your help.

Comment: If you look at it geometrically, then $\theta$ obviously goes to $\phi$ as $r\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: i am not sure for your response. the prove is needed. I did some test and find that the final value of $\theta$ depends on $\theta_0$,$x_0$ and $y_0$.

Comment: Just a few fine points regarding your question statement: the way I read it, the case where $\lvert AP\rvert>2$ is rather irrelevant, since then $A$ just moves in a straight line and $\theta$ remains constant. So we might as well start with $\lvert AP\rvert=2$, in which case $r_0$ is irrelevant, since $2=\lvert AP\rvert/2$ defines the radius. Furthermore, $\theta_0$ seems to be irrelevant, since it is determined by $A_0$, right? Except if you want to choose between the two possible tangents, which would complicate things without adding much insight, I think. You'd just turn the other way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Some analysis

I choose $x$ as a free parameter, and $y(x)$ as a function to describe the movement. You want $l=2r$ which you can rewrite as

\begin{align*}
x^2+(y-r)^2&=(2r)^2\\
x^2+y^2-2yr+r^2&=4r^2\\
3r^2+2yr-(x^2+y^2)&=0\\
r&=\frac{-y+\sqrt{3x^2+4y^2}}{3}
\end{align*}

The other solution of the quadratic equation would result in $r<0$ and can therefore be omitted. Now you know that

$$\overrightarrow{PA}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y-r\end{pmatrix}
=\frac13\begin{pmatrix}3x\\4y-\sqrt{3x^2+4y^2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Rotate that right by $60°$ and scale it by $6$ and you get

$$12\overrightarrow{PQ}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&\sqrt3\\-\sqrt3&1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot3\overrightarrow{PA}=
\begin{pmatrix}
3x+\sqrt3\left(4y-\sqrt{3x^2 + 4y^2}\right)\\
-3\sqrt{3} x + 4y - \sqrt{3x^2 + 4y^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

That vector has to be orthogonal to the direction of the movement, namely

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\y'\end{pmatrix}$$

so their dot product must be zero. This will give you a relation between $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$:

$$
y'=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=
-\frac{3x+\sqrt3\left(4y-\sqrt{3x^2 + 4y^2}\right)}
{-3\sqrt{3} x + 4y - \sqrt{3x^2 + 4y^2}}
$$

## Interpreting this formula

Now I don't have enough experience to solve this beast analytically (if that is at all possible), and for a numeric solution we would need precise starting conditions. But a look at the slope field might be instructive:

[image: Slope field]

That does look reasonable to me.

## Convegence claim

One thing worth noting is that the whole problem is scale invariant (at least if you are in the regime where the circle shrinks with the approaching point). If you multiply all lengths with a common factor, the slope remains the same. So if the slope converges towards the end, it means that the final direction must be a fixpoint, so starting from that direction at *any* distance will cause movement in a straight line towards the origin. But there is only one direction which matches movement directly to the origin in the initial situation, and that is horizontal. That's because the tangent at the origin is horizontal.

So I'd say the slope converges towards horizontal eventually, no matter the initial conditions. In the limit, $\theta=0$.

## Numerical experiments

The convergence is very slow towards the end, though. In the following animation, I'm using the distance $OA$ as a scale factor for the speed, and dowards the end the change in the slope of the line $AB$ is hardly perceptible any more. So I can see how numeric experiments would indicate a non-zero limit. Nevertheless, the apparent final slope cannot be the real final slope, because if it were, then slopes along that line would have to point directly towards the origin, which they do not.

Also note that the convergence only appears slow in this parametrization with adaptice speed. If you use fixed speed, you will reach the point where $x=0$ in finite time. But obtaining precise numeric results for this case is hard, which is the reason why I consdier this adaptiveness and the resulting slow convergence to be reasonable.

[image: Animation]

## Change in angle

In a comment, you asked about characterizing the convergence in terms of a Lyapunov exponent. For that we'd need to fix a reasonable parameter space. Since the problem is scale invariant, I'd use the angle which $OA$ makes againt horizontal as the sole description of phase space. Let's call that angle $\alpha$, with $\tan\alpha=y/x$. For the time dependence, I'll consider a point at unit distance from the origon, traveling at unit speed towards $Q$. This formulation models the rescaling I used above. Now consider the following differential equation:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos(\alpha+\mathrm d\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha+\mathrm d\alpha)} =
\frac{\cos\alpha-\mathrm d\alpha\sin\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\mathrm d\alpha\cos\alpha}
= \frac{x-y\,\mathrm d\alpha}{y+x\,\mathrm d\alpha}
&= \frac{x+\mathrm dt\,\Delta x}{y+\mathrm dt\,\Delta y}
\\
(x-y\,\mathrm d\alpha)(y+\mathrm dt\,\Delta y) &=
(y+x\,\mathrm d\alpha)(x+\mathrm dt\,\Delta x)
\\
x\,\Delta y\,\mathrm dt-y^2\,\mathrm d\alpha &=
y\,\Delta x\,\mathrm dt+x^2\,\mathrm d\alpha \\
(x^2+y^2)\mathrm d\alpha = \mathrm d\alpha &= (x\,\Delta y-y\,\Delta x)\mathrm dt
\\
\dot\alpha = \frac{\mathrm d\alpha}{\mathrm dt} &= x\,\Delta y-y\,\Delta x
\end{align*}

Here I assume $x=\cos\alpha,y=\sin\alpha$ and also assume $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ to be a unit length vector pointing from $A$ to $Q$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\Delta x\\\Delta y\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\y'\end{pmatrix}$$

at least for the case where $y'>0$. For $y'<0$ we want the opposite sign; those are the parts where we move down and right. But for the simpler case of $y'<0$ we get

\begin{align*}
\dot\alpha=
\frac{\mathrm d\alpha}{\mathrm dt}&=
\frac{y-xy'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}
\end{align*}

Fixing the sign over the whole range, you get the following as a plot of the change in angle (or rather its negative, for better placement of labels):

[image: Change in angle]

Or here a close-up of the last degree:

[image: Close-up]

As you can see, the smaller the angle, the smaller its change will be. But the change will always be negative, so the tangent will always move towards horizontal.

Now that I think about it, it will be difficult to express this in terms of a (global) Lyapunov exponent: On the one hand there is a high change rate for large angles, whereas for arbitrarily small angles, the change rate can become arbitrarily slow as well. But I've not much experience dealing with Lyapunov exponents, so perhaps you can find a better formulation for this.

Looking at these graphs, it should be possible to show that $\dot\alpha<0$ for $\alpha\in(0°,90°]$, thereby demonstrating the convergence

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\alpha(t)=0$$

which in turn implies $\theta=0$ and $\varphi=-\frac\pi6=-30°$ in that limit.

## Constant speed

Also please remember that the slow convergence is a result of adaptive step width. If you move at uniform speed, e.g. from $x_0=y_0=1$, then angle as a function of time will look like this:

[image: Angle as function of time]

You can obtain such a graph with reasonable precision if you do the adaptive step width approach, but keep track of the curve length so far and use that as the $t$ coordinate for the data point. This will give you a lot of points on the near vertical axis at the far right.

The near-vertical slope there will tell you that the difference between correctly representing the convergence and overshooting the $x=0$ situation is *very* slim.

Comment: In fact I get the equation of $y'$ myself, but I don't really agree with your last two paragraphs, unfortunately I have no convincing reasons. I did some numerical tests and defined the sampling time as small as possible, finally the limit is not $0$. I think some mathmatic deductions are needed. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @Martial: I just did some numerical tests as well, and I'd say the convergence is terribly slow. I'm still convinced that things will converge to zero eventually, mathematically speaking. Is there some aspect of my argument which you find unconvincing, or is it just the fact that your numerical experiments seem to indicate otherwise?

Comment: the result of my test is just like your animation. there is an angle non zero in the end... I don't know whether its limit is zero. perhaps as you say, the convergence will be very slow, but it will be better if we have some demonstrations using mathmatic methods, like Lyapunov etc.

Comment: thank you, your answer is instructive, I will spend some time to study it.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the beautifull result of MvG, it is possible to integrate $$
y'=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=
-\frac{3x+\sqrt3\left(4y-\sqrt{3x^2 + 4y^2}\right)}
{-3\sqrt{3} x + 4y - \sqrt{3x^2 + 4y^2}}
$$
and finally obtain an equivalent  $-2\sqrt(3)\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ for the function $y(x)$. This proves that $y(x)$ tends to $0$ for $x$ tending to $0$

[image]

The preceeding result leads to the equation of the family of curves expressed on parametric form (the parameter is $z$).

This shows that all the curves are homothetic. The factor $C$ is determined by the initial point. So, it is sufficient to draw only one curve (for example $C=1$) to show the behaviour of all.

For small values of the parameter $z$, the point $(x,y)$ is closed to $0$. In order to clearly see the decreassing of $\theta$ while $z$ tends to $0$, it is necessary to go to very small values. This is due to the logarithmic term in the equivalent function. This is clear below on the several graphs with different magnitudes.

[image]

When $z$ tends to infinity, $x$ tends to $0$ and $y$ tends to $y_{max} = e^{-2+\Re(\tanh^{-1}(2) ) } $ approximately $= 0.234408$ where $\Re(\tanh^{-1}(2))$ is the real part of $\tanh^{-1}(2)$ which is complex.

Comment: yes, the point $A$ will definitively converge to the origin. What I want to know is the limit of the angle $\theta$

Comment: Of course, we know that $A$ will converge to the origin. What is the key result is the equivalent equation at the origine : $y=-2\sqrt3 \frac{x}{ln(x)}$. One can imediately deduce that $\tan(\theta)=\frac{dy}{dx} = -2\sqrt3(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}-\frac{1}{\ln(x)^2})$ converges to $0$ and $\theta$ also.

Comment: yes, you are right, i didn't notice that. But I have a question: what is the reason to suppose $y=zx$? here $z$ is a function of $x$? and this equation could cover all the possibilties of the function $y(x)$? Thank you:

Comment: The ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ is of the homogeneous kind because changing $x$ to $cx$ and $y$ to $cy$ doesn't change $\frac{dy}{dx}$. The usual way to solve such kind of ODE is a change of variable $y=x z(x)$. I used this method without looking for something else insofar it leads to the result.

Comment: Addition to my preceeding comment : " changing $x$ to $cx$ and $y$ to $cy$ doesn't change $\frac{dy}{dx}$ " because one can see that $f(x,y)=f(cx,cy)$

Comment: Thanks. I have another question: in the equation $\ln|x|=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{z}+C-\dots$, why can we omit the terms like $z,z^2,O(z^3)$? I think it should base on the fact that $z=y/x$ is very close to $0$, but this is not clear here.

Comment: More information are added to my preceeding answer. I hope it will be clearer. By the way, I will be absent for some time. Excuse me if there is no more response from me.

Comment: It should be valuable to verify my calculus because I did it in a rush without serious numerical tests.

Comment: yes, I will. Thanks very much for your help. I did also some calculations thanks to the inspiration of your answer and find that while $z=1+\sqrt(3),x_{max}=0.03758$(this is shown also in your graph), if $x<x_{max}$, $y(x)$ and $\theta$ are exactly converge to $0$. I think that we don't need to consider the range $x>x_{max}$(there is no solution for $z$), because I can prove $dx/dt<0$, and $x$ will finally go into the range $<x_{max}$. am I right?

Comment: I agree. I only began to study what happens for larger $z$. It is complicated because the $\tanh^{-1}(...)$ are on the complex domain. I arrived at this result (still not confirmed) : for $z$ tending to infinity $y_{max}=\exp(-2+\frac{1}{2}(\tanh^{-1}(2+\epsilon i)+\tanh^{-1}(2-\epsilon i)) = 0.234408...$ with $\epsilon$ tending to $0$ and on the correct path in the complex domain. But I agree that is not usefull to answer to the initial question.

Comment: I verified your answer, and found that $\tan(\theta)=dy/dx=-\frac{-\ln x+8+\ln x\sqrt{\frac{\ln^2 x+16}{\ln^2 x}}\sqrt{3}}{3\ln x+8+\ln x\sqrt{\frac{\ln^2 x+16}{\ln^2 x}}}$, but didn't get your function $dy/dx=-2\sqrt{3}(\frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{\ln^2 x})$, though my result converge to $0$ also. Could you please explain how you got that result?

Comment: $-2\sqrt3(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}-\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)})$ is not equal to $\frac{dy}{dx}$. It is the equivalent to $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $x$ tends to $0$ . It is derived from the equivalent to $y(x)$ which is the first term of the asymptotic expansion of $y(x)$ for $\ln(x)$ tending to -$\infty$. In fact, the term $2\sqrt3\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}$ is of no importance and the equivalent of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ simply is $-2\sqrt3\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$